# How do I retrieve the image component of an iOS live photo from the Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api, apple-live-photos

We fetch a lot of media from Google's Drive API on behalf of our users. We care about photos and videos and we determine which is which via the mime type. The files endpoint is what we use to do this:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

However, since about mid-2016 Google Photos began backing up iOS live photos, which have a still image component and a video component. My questions is, how do I programmatically determine which is which and once I've detected a live photo, how do I access just the image component?

In practice what I've found is that live photos return as `video/mp4` with a file extension of `.JPG`. However, the only image I have access to is a thumbnail.